# Отключить защиту от атак по умолчанию в spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно отключить заданную по умолчанию защиту от атак в spring security.

я так понимаю это делается где то в методе

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

а нашел в доках)
 .csrf().disable();